# How can I set specific country and specific IP for Tor browser in Windows?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I have set my **Tor browser** to use only **US** country using `ExitNodes` but how can I also set it to use **specific IP** and not a random one? If it can be done...

Comment: You can use the same config option, but pass the fingerprint of the relay you want to use instead of just the country.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks: Can I have an example please?

Comment: If you go to [this](https://torstatus.blutmagie.de/) page which lists all the Tor relays, and click on the name of one of the relays, then you'll be taken to a page that contains details of the relay, including its fingerprint. Then, for example: `ExitNodes ec116bcb80565a408ce67f8ec3fe3b0b02c3a065` for the relay on [this](https://torstatus.blutmagie.de/router_detail.php?FP=ec116bcb80565a408ce67f8ec3fe3b0b02c3a065) page.